# Analysis of the XMI exported by enterprise architect tool's UML diagram

Tags: xml, uml, enterprise-architect, xmi

How to know the details about the various tags(Ex: UML:Message, UML:Diagram, UML:Component) present in the XMI file which is exported from the sequence diagram developed using the Enterprise architect tool?

Comment: Have you looked into OMG's XMI definition?

Comment: Yeah I have referred to that.. But it is not clearly documented even in that web page.

Answer (score 1):

There is no publicly available documentation for EA's XMI extensions.

The XMI file format is standardized by OMG, the standardization body which controls UML. The format is designed to be extensible, so that the tool vendors can add their own extensions. These extensions are proprietary and documentation for them is typically not available to end users, except possibly for open-source tools.

Comment: The problem is I'm currently using Enterprise Architect 9.1 which is not a open-source tool.

Comment: No, it isn''t. So you'd have to contact the vendor (Sparx Systems) to see if they'd be willing to supply you with the necessary documentation.